# How to capture first response on case via trigger?

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I need to create a way to capture when the first response. I then need to measure how long time between when the Case was opened and       when it was first responded.

I created two fields: 
Time_to_First_Response__c 
First_Response__c

I need to capture the first response and measure the time to first response in a trigger.

First Response is defined as when the case owner user makes any edit to the case or logs an activity against the case.

Time to First Response Calculation: 
I need to NOT include when the office is closed (nights, weekends, holidays) in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a trigger to update First_Response_Date.

To calculate the `Time_to_First_Response__c` create a utility class as below and pass the startDate and endDate to calculate the time in business hours.

Also, define business hour in salesforce org prior to that.

```
public with sharing class BusinessHoursServices
{
    //retrieves & assign the Organization level Business Hours to defaultBH 
    @testVisible static BusinessHours defaultBH
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultBH == null)
                defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            return defaultBH;
        }
        private set;
    }

    /**
    * getBusinessHourTimeDifference
    * returns business hours difference in milliseconds based on two datetime. 
    * @param businessHoursId - BusinessHour Id
    * @param startDate - start date time
    * @param endDate - end date time
    * @return Long
    */
    public static Long getBusinessHourTimeDifference(Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
    {
        return BusinessHours.diff(defaultBH.Id, startDate, endDate);
    }

    public static String getDuration(Long inputMillisecs) 
    {               
        Integer total_duration_in_seconds = (inputMillisecs/1000).intValue(); //duration in seconds

        Integer year_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/31556926).intValue(),10000000); //number of years
        Integer day_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/86400).intValue(),365); //number of days
        Integer hour_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/3600).intValue(),24); //number of hours
        Integer minute_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/60).intValue(),60); //number of minutes
        Integer second_result = math.mod(math.floor(total_duration_in_seconds/1).intValue(),60); //number of seconds

        String year_text_string = segment_text('Year', year_result, ''); //string variable for text regarding Year
        String day_text_string = segment_text('Day', day_result, year_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Day
        String hour_text_string = segment_text('Hour', hour_result, year_text_string + day_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Hour
        String minute_text_string = segment_text('Minute', minute_result, year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Minute
        String second_text_string = segment_text('Second', second_result, year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string + minute_text_string); //string variable for text regarding Second
        String return_string = year_text_string + day_text_string + hour_text_string + minute_text_string + second_text_string;//concatenate all the strings into one for our resutling test string
        return return_string; //pass back the final string
    }
}
```

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void segment_text(String, Integer, String) from the type BusinessHoursServices